# Flask routes are getting 404

Tags: python, flask

This is how my project (simple url shorterner) is set up. I wanted to have two different environments, for development easy run, and for production using gunicorn.

```
├── app.py
├── config.py
├── gunicorn-starter.sh
└── tinyURL
    ├── encoder.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── routes.py
    └── shortener.py
```

This is routes.py:

```py
from flask import request, jsonify

from tinyURL import create_app

app = create_app()


@app.route('/encode', methods=['POST'])
def encode():
    """Endpoint that encodes a URL to a shortened URL."""
    pass


@app.route('/decode/<short_code>', methods=['GET'])
def decode(short_code):
    """Endpoint that decodes a shortened URL to its original URL."""
    pass
```

this is _*init_*.py

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_class='config.DevelopmentConfig'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    return app
```

this is app.py

```py
from tinyURL import create_app

application = create_app("config.ProductionConfig")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

and gunicorn-starter.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh

gunicorn tinyURL:"create_app('config.ProductionConfig')" -w 4 --threads 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

The problem is that by running both app.py and gunicorn-starter.sh, both endpoints return 404. How can I fix these two?

----- Update:
Server output for two different request:

```bash
"POST /encode HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /decode/0000 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Curl output (response):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Comment: Show us the console output.

Comment: @KlausD. Updated the question with output.

Comment: Is this your complete code? If so, you need to return something in the route functions, right now they only have `pass` so they don't do anything.

Comment: @Rob Yes, my code is complete, for the sake of simplicity, I removed the unrelated parts.

Comment: I think you may have gone too simple. At least include a return value in your functions, otherwise it just looks like nonsense - and makes it impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating two flask apps, one which has the routes and one that does not.

So the app in `routes.py`is not the same as the one in `app.py`.

One way to solve it would be to use the app created in `routes.py` in your `app.py` by doing this

```py
from tinyURL.routes import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and maybe adding the configuration in the main before the run.

This is a bit of a design question what you want to do, where you want to have your app and routes defined. You could wrap the routes into a function and have a `create_routes` function in `routes.py`. So you can have the logic of creating and configuration in your `app.py`.

routes.py

```py
def create_routes(app):
    @app.route('/encode', methods=['POST'])
    def encode():
        """Endpoint that encodes a URL to a shortened URL."""
        pass

    @app.route('/decode/<short_code>', methods=['GET'])
    def decode(short_code):
        """Endpoint that decodes a shortened URL to its original URL."""
        # Added this simple return for testing via my browser
        return 'Ok', True
```

app.py

```py
from tinyURL import create_app
from tinyURL.routes import create_routes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    create_routes(app)
    app.run()
```

Another way is to use the `add_url_rule` function, so you do not need a wrapper and have the logic what routes you have in your `app.py` but the functionality in `routes.py`

routes.py

```py
def decode(short_code):
    """Endpoint that decodes a shortened URL to its original URL."""
    # Added this simple return for testing via my browser
    return 'Ok', True
```

app.py

```py
from tinyURL import create_app
from tinyURL.routes import decode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.add_url_rule('/decode/<short_code>', view_func=decode, methods=['GET'])
    app.run()
```

or just simply define the routes as normal in the `app.py` but have them act as more of a wrapper, but then be careful how to name things.

routes.py

```py
def decode(short_code):
    """Endpoint that decodes a shortened URL to its original URL."""
    return 'Ok', True
```

app.py

```py
from tinyURL import create_app
from tinyURL.routes import decode

app = create_app()


@app.route('/decode/<short_code>', methods=['GET'])
def decode_route(short_code):
    """Endpoint that decodes a shortened URL to its original URL."""
    return decode(short_code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

There are probably 100 more ways to do this. My flask server always defined the routes in the `app.py` and I maybe just had functionalities in other files, if they were more complex.

As said it is a design choice, how and where, the key part is that you need to make sure you only ever have one instance of a flask object which you pass around.